# Javascript problems after .NET 4.0 conversion

Tags: javascript, .net, .net-4.0, addeventlistener

I used the automatic conversion wizard to upgrade a collection of web services from 1.1 to 4.0.  In the solution there is also one website.  Since conversion it is not behaving correctly.

On one page, there is a javascript validation function that checks to see if at least one of a group of checkboxes is checked before a report is allowed to run.  The page posts back to itself to display the report, and there is a "new report" linkbutton that returns to the search criteria page.

When the new report lb is clicked in the converted page, it fires that validation and says "please select criteria" even though the checkboxes don't exist.  I can fix that, but I would like to understand why this is occurring so I don't have to test all over the site for similar problems.

Perhaps related, or perhaps more important, now I am getting "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'" all over the place, apparently from Infragistics script, even though I am using IE9 to debug.  Running the 1.1 version of this site on an old machine with IE8 doesn't have any of these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in regards to your last paragraph, for IE versions later than 8, you need to use the attachEvent instead of addEventListener. IE 9+ does not support it anymore. This could be the reason you're experiencing those other issues, too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

example:

```
div.attachEvent("onmousedown", handleMouseDown);
```

Comment: Although I had seen the issue of IE9 and later after googling, I misunderstood it as the opposite of the reality - that addEventListener was ONLY supported in IE9 and later.  This indeed took care of the Infragistics errors.  However, the validation problems remain.